# spring hibernate jpa many to many

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I try to ask patients for a doctor like this in my service.
At first I add some pets to a doctor. Then when I try to get the list of pets, it will be returned, but after records will be removed from doctor_pet join table and next time the result will be an empty list.

```
@RequestMapping(value = ["/{id}/patients"], method = [RequestMethod.GET], produces = ["application/json"])
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
fun getPatients(@PathVariable("id") id: Long): ResponseEntity<List<Pet>> = ResponseEntity(doctorService.getPets(id), HttpStatus.OK)
```

Doctor class look like this

```
@Entity
class Doctor: Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long = 0

    lateinit var name: String
    @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinTable(name = "doctor_pet"
            , joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id")]
            , inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "pet_id")])
    var pets = mutableListOf<Pet>()
}
```

Pet look like this

```
@Entity
class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long = 0
    lateinit var name: String
    var yearOfBorn: Int = 0

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "pets")
    var doctors = mutableListOf<Doctor>()

    override fun toString(): String = "$name was born in $yearOfBorn."
}
```

And I get the list of pets from DoctorDao repository like this.

```
// Get pets for doctor from DoctorDaoImpl
override fun getPets(id: Long): List<Pet> {
    val doctor = entityManager.find(Doctor::class.java, id)
    return doctor.pets
}

@Repository
@Transactional
open class DoctorServiceImpl @Autowired constructor(@Qualifier("doctorDao") val doctorDao: DoctorDao) : DoctorService {

    override fun saveDoctor(doctor: Doctor) {
        doctorDao.saveDoctor(doctor)
    }

    override fun updateDoctor(doctor: Doctor) {
        doctorDao.updateDoctor(doctor)
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    override fun findDoctor(id: Long): Doctor = doctorDao.findDoctor(id)

    override fun getPets(id: Long): List<Pet> = doctorDao.getPets(id)
}
```

What do I wrong?

**update**

After I get pets from DoctorDao I

> Hibernate: delete from doctor_pet where doctor_id=?

The whole log is

> Hibernate: select doctor0_.id as id0_0_, doctor0_.name as name0_0_
>   from Doctor doctor0_ where doctor0_.id=? Hibernate: select
>   pets0_.doctor_id as doctor1_0_1_, pets0_.pet_id as pet2_4_1_, pet1_.id
>   as id1_0_, pet1_.name as name1_0_, pet1_.yearOfBorn as yearOfBorn1_0_
>   from doctor_pet pets0_ inner join Pet pet1_ on pets0_.pet_id=pet1_.id
>   where pets0_.doctor_id=? Hibernate: delete from doctor_pet where
>   doctor_id=? Hibernate: select doctors0_.pet_id as pet2_1_1_,
>   doctors0_.doctor_id as doctor1_4_1_, doctor1_.id as id0_0_,
>   doctor1_.name as name0_0_ from doctor_pet doctors0_ inner join Doctor
>   doctor1_ on doctors0_.doctor_id=doctor1_.id where doctors0_.pet_id=?

Comment: Maybe you're missing @Transactional on your Service class? See https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring

Comment: +Ryan Dawson, I set <tx:annotation-drinven> and I declared a transactionManager as well.
All my services are transactional.
If I add link pet to doctor, I can see in MySql Workbrencs it was successful, and at the first time when I query pets for doctor, pets are listed, but I can in workbrencs the join table is empty right after the query finished.

Comment: I'm very new to Spring/Hibernate/Jpa. I tried out all day how to solve it. Why joinable will be cleared after get the pet list from a doctor, but I wasn't able to. I'm going to share my bitbucket repo.